# Removing charaters from a txt file

Tags: python

How do i open my txt file and remove som special characters form some tweets from a txt file.

My text looks somthing like this

```
@xirwinshemmo thanks for the follow :)
hii... if u want to make a new friend just add me on facebook! :) xx https:\/\/t.co\/RCYFVrmdDG
@ycmaP enjoy tmrro. saw them earlier this wk here in tokyo :)
```

I have to get rid of everything  that starts with @ 
and every webpage (http)
How do i do that?

I have tried this so far.

```
 import re

 a = []
 with open('englishtweets1.txt','r') as inf:
      a = inf.readlines()
for line in a:
    line = re.sub(r['@'], line)
```

Comment: [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) takes three arguments.

Comment: Maybe you could try something like this: $my_text=file_get_contents('textfile.txt'); $new_text=preg_replace("@", "", $my_text);

Comment: what can i use for the third argument then?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. If you want to remove the matched part, use an empty string `""` as the replacement. Mor difficult is the regular expression to match what you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

use it like this

```
import re
data = open('englishtweets1.txt').read()
new_str = re.sub(r'^@', ' ', data)
new_str = re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', new_str, flags=re.MULTILINE)
#open('removed.txt', 'w').write(new_str) (if needed)
```

**UPDATE**
This is working just tested

```
new_str = re.sub(r'https.(.*?) ', '', new_str, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: That will not "get rid of everything that starts with @".

Comment: i used it like you did it worked but how it do not get rid of everything. The username is stil there and in the http the rest of the http is stil there

Answer (score 1):

### All in one go

If your file is not huge you can do it all in one go:

```
import re
with open('englishtweets1.txt') as f:
    contents = re.sub(r'^@\w+\s|\bhttp[^\s]+', '', f.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)
print contents
```

Result:

> thanks for the follow :)
>   hii... if u want to make a new friend just add me on facebook! :) xx
>   enjoy tmrro. saw them earlier this wk here in tokyo :)

Note that the http stripping is very simple and will strip away anything beginning with http. To fix that, you can improve the regex to search for valid http urls.

### Line by line

If your file is very large, you might not want to store it all in memory. You can instead iterate over all lines in the file:

```
import re
with open('englishtweets1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print re.sub(r'^@\w+\s|\bhttp[^\s]+', '', line)
```

Comment: Did it pose any problems? I've added a line by line version too.